# Qual o significado de "acrescentado" em poema de Alberto Caeiro?

Tags: significado-em-contexto, mudanças-históricas

Em [*O Guardador de Rebandos*](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/pesquisa/DetalheObraForm.do?select_action=&co_obra=15723), de Alberto Caeiro (pseudónimo de Fernando Pessoa), consta o seguinte no poema V (grifo meu):

> Pensar no sentido íntimo das cousas
> **É acrescentado**, como pensar na saúde
> Ou levar um copo à água das fontes.
>
> O único sentido íntimo das cousas
> É elas não terem sentido íntimo nenhum.

Como muitos aqui decerto sabem, Alberto Caeiro era bem naturalista, desdenha da Metafísica e
nesse poema isso fica muito claro.

Minha pergunta é: Nesse contexto, em que Alberto está criticando aqueles que ficam procurando o sentido íntimo das coisas,
qual o sentido de dizer que isso é **acrescentado**?

O dicionário Aulete define o [verbete acrescentar](http://www.aulete.com.br/acrescentar) das maneiras bem conhecidas (adicionar e somar), e traz
ainda o sentido figurativo

> Tornar (algo ou alguém) maior, melhor, mais rico etc. auferindo-lhe bens, qualidades, benefícios, vantagens etc.

Mas não creio que Alberto esteja usando nenhum desses sentidos na frase transcripta. Será alguma acepção que caiu em desuso? Outros dicionários também não me ajudaram, por isso esta pergunta.

<sup>Aliás, caso se interesse, há no canal da Univesp TV um ótimo [recital de alguns desses poemas de Fernando pessoa por Lima Barreto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4Znbg3RBLA).</sup>

Comment: A mim, soa como "é, eu acrescento, como pensar na saúde",

Comment: @Centaurus Se assim fosse, seriam necessárias duas vírgulas ("É, acrescentado, como pensar na saúde"), não? Talvez não me esteja lembrando bem, mas seria um aposto.

Comment: Realmente, mas é o único significado que me ocorre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendo como significando que não é intrínseco, que nós que atribuiríamos "sentido íntimo" às coisas - ou seja, que nós acrescentamos isso a elas, é algo "acrescentado".